# Space increase between array

Tags: positioning, arrays

Question-1

I want to increase space front side and backside of semicolon(;).

Question-2

I want to change position of y->\infty at downward side (Same as at y->0)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.8 in,bottom=0.8 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.5 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\begin{document}
\large
The associated boundary conditions are

\(\begin{array}[t].{l}\}
u = U_{0} \\[8pt]
v = V_{w} \\ [8pt]
N = 0 \\ [8pt]
T = T_{w} \\ [8pt]
C = C_{w} 
\end{array}_{at\; y \,\to \,0}
\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}\\{}; {}\\{}\end{array}
\begin{array}[t].{l}\}
u \,\to\, 0\\[8pt]
N \,\to\, 0\\[8pt]
T \,\to\, T_{\infty}\\[8pt]
C \,\to\, C_{\infty}
\end{array}\)_{as\; y \,\to \,\infty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are aware that your example does not compile? For example why do you have `\(...\)_{as\; y \,\to \,\infty}` as the `_{as\; y \,\to \,\infty}` part requires math mode and `\)` ends inline math mode.

Comment: @daleif Its compile good at my end.

Comment: Are you sure?  `Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.34 \end{array}\)_
                   {as\; y \,\to \,\infty}`

Comment: If this compliles at your end (and your end is not Overleaf where a failed compilation is often overlooked) then please provide the log file from compiling exactly this MWE

Comment: My end is overleaf

Comment: And don't you get a big red button that says the compilation failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a subscript outside of math mode.

I believe it's better to use a display and also align differently the contents. I propose both top alignment and center alignment (which I'd prefer).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.8 in,bottom=0.8 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.5 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}
The associated boundary conditions are
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}[t].{@{}r@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}l@{}}\}
u &=& U_{0} \\
v &=& V_{w} \\
N &=& 0 \\
T &=& T_{w} \\
C &=& C_{w} 
\end{array}_{\text{as $y \to 0$}}
\quad ; \quad
\begin{array}[t].{@{}r@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}l@{}}\}
u &\to& 0\\
N &\to& 0\\
T &\to& T_{\infty}\\
C &\to& C_{\infty}
\end{array}_{\text{as $y \to \infty$}}
\]
The associated boundary conditions are
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\left.
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}l@{}}
u &=& U_{0} \\
v &=& V_{w} \\
N &=& 0 \\
T &=& T_{w} \\
C &=& C_{w} 
\end{array}
\right\}_{\text{as $y \to 0$}}
\quad ; \quad
\left.
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}l@{}}
u &\to& 0\\
N &\to& 0\\
T &\to& T_{\infty}\\
C &\to& C_{\infty}
\end{array}
\right\}_{\text{as $y \to \infty$}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a third possibility:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.8 in,bottom=0.8 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.5 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}
The associated boundary conditions are
\[
\left.
\begin{aligned}
u &= U_{0} \\
v &= V_{w} \\
N &= 0 \\
T &= T_{w} \\
C &= C_{w} 
\end{aligned}
\right\}\text{as $y \to 0$};\quad
\left.
\begin{aligned}
u &\to 0\\
N &\to 0\\
T &\to T_{\infty}\\
C &\to C_{\infty}
\end{aligned}
\right\}\text{as $y \to \infty$}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great.. Thanks a lot sir. May I change position of as y->0, I mean can we write in center instead of below.

Comment: @Snehal I added a further possibility

Comment: In above last code of boundary conditions Can we give equation number? Because I have been working with lots of equations and this one is in the intermediate level.

Comment: @Snehal Use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` instead of `\[...\]`

Comment: ok I understand once again thanks. Hoping that I will get benefit of your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

In Plain TeX, we can use `\eqalign{...}` as a part of the math formula.

```
$$
  \left.\eqalign{u &= U_0\cr w &= V_w\cr N &= 0\cr T &= T_w\cr C &= C_w}\right\}
   _{{\rm as}\ y\,\to\,\infty}
  \quad ; \quad
  \left.\eqalign{u &\to 0\cr N &\to 0\cr T &\to T_\infty\cr C &\to  C_\infty}\right\}
  _{{\rm as}\ y\,\to\,\infty}
$$

\bye
```